# QUERY with IMPORTRANGE between two different sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I'm trying to connect 2 separated Google Sheets with Query and Importrange functions but I'm not able to make them working.
Basically there is a master Sheet (called SheetA) where there are several values and a SheetB which is pulling data.

On SheetB I'm not able to make the formulas working, giving me #Error.
I'll attach both the sheets here:

SheetA: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lixylYu6H6yYfl3cjPVVdRYuS-C8V3_0tWbLRWPBbx8/edit?usp=sharing

SheetB: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19NPs067xOq5hX97RrZ0O_-jhBgK4qkKtzRs9lM-LPt4/edit?usp=sharing

You should be able to see the formula in there so you can understand what I'm trying to achieve.
Also I've made them both Editable so feel free to adjust them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LOCALE setting is Italy. In this environment configuration the standard delimiter of Google Formulae is ";" instead of the "," which is used in US LOCALE for example.

Changing each comma to a semi-colon in your Spreadsheet will solve the #Error issues.

### Reference

[LOCALE Settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1lixylYu6H6yYfl3cjPVVdRYuS-C8V3_0tWbLRWPBbx8", $A$1&"!A2")
```

use:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1lixylYu6H6yYfl3cjPVVdRYuS-C8V3_0tWbLRWPBbx8"; $A$1&"!A2")
```